How to determine the timing of multi-note appoggiaturas?
I know that appoggiaturas are played on the beat and that the appoggiatura takes half the time of the following note, except when followed by a dotted note. Then it usually takes two-thirds of the value of the note.

Now assuming that we're following the same rules, how does this work with double or triple appoggiaturas? Are there any timing rules or is it just play it quickly? How would you determine the timing of the section below where a double appoggiatura of two 16th notes are leading into an 8th note?

I found this image where the double appoggiaturas are written out but I'm not sure I understand how the timing works or how one would determine that.

So my questions are how would one determine the timing of double/triple appoggiaturas (if at all) and how does the appoggiatura being an 8th or 16th note effect the timing? Can appoggiaturas be quarter notes, half notes or any other type?

The latest image seems the same found on the wikipedia page, which also says that "the double appoggiatura, in which the first note lies at a distance from the principal note, should always be somewhat slower than that in which both notes are close to it". Note, though, that there is no absolute rule for compound appoggiaturas, it may depend on the period of the composition, how accurate the rendition attempt may be (and its research, consider "historically informed performance"), and, finally, personal taste of the performer.

Double or triple grace appoggiaturas have no fixed duration.

Okay thanks. Just one more clarification: Why do some music scores use 8th notes for double appoggiaturas and quarter notes for single appoggiaturas instead of what's shown above? Is it simply up to the style and taste of the composer?
